# Write a formula in an Excel Cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use VBA to write a formula into a cell in Excel.
My problem is that when I use a semicolon (`;`) in my formula, I get an error:

> **`Run-time error 1004`**

My macro is the following :

```
Sub Jours_ouvres()
    Dim Feuille_Document As String
    Feuille_Document = "DOCUMENT"        
    Application.Worksheets(Feuille_Document).Range("F2").Formula = "=SUM(D2;E2)"    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try using FormulaLocal property instead of Formula. Then the semicolon should work.

Comment: Good point! I did not realize that excel formulas could use different characters in different locales (!) what a nightmare!

Answer (score 5):

The correct character to use in this case is a full colon (`:`), not a semicolon (`;`).

Answer (score 5):

The correct character (comma or colon) depends on the purpose.

Comma (`,`) will sum only the two cells in question.

Colon (`:`) will sum all the cells within the range with corners defined by those two cells.

Comment: This is not the reason for the error. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Treb, Matthieu's problem was caused by using Excel in a non-English language. In many language versions ";" is the correct separator. Even functions are translated (SUM can be SOMMA, SUMME or whatever depending on what language you work in). Excel will generally understand these differences and if a French-created workbook is opened by a Brazilian they will normally not have any problem.
But **VBA** speaks only US English so for those of us working in one (or more) foreign langauges, this can be a headache.
You and CharlesB both gave answers that would have been OK for a US user but Mikko understod the REAL problem and gave the correct answer (which was also the correct one for me too - I'm a Brit working in Italy for a German-speaking company).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but if you use

```
(...)Formula = "=SUM(D2,E2)"
```

('***,***' instead of '***;***'), it works.

If you step through your sub in the VB script editor (F8), you can add `Range("F2").Formula` to the watch window and see what the formular looks like from a VB point of view. It seems that the formular shown in Excel itself is sometimes different from the formular that VB sees...

Comment: That formula adds only cells D2 and E2. It works in this case, because that range only had two cells. If the range was D2:G2, for example, using the comma would add only the first and last cells in the range: D2 and G2, not all four of them.

Comment: To the downvoters: While eJames is correct in his more genereic answer, my answer is correct in this specific case. If you downvote, explain why.