# What is wrong with my OFFSET formula for data validation?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, offset

I keep getting stuck on OFFSET part. When I try it manually, it works, when I try it with VBA it gets stuck!

```
Range("C2").Activate
    With ActiveCell.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= _
    "=OFFSET(PARTSDB!$A$1;MATCH(CONCATENATE($E2;"" 
"";$F2);PARTSDB!$A:$A;0)-1;1;COUNTIF(PARTSDB!$A:$A;CONCATENATE($E2;"" 
"";$F2));1)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "ERROR!!!"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = _
    "PART YOU ENTER DOESNT EXIST!!!"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: Define "stuck"...  Need more information. What data is in C2 that you're validating?  What's an example of a correct value, and an incorrect value?

Comment: I get "Run-time error '1004': Im validating list of "parts" that goes on certain model. Like creating dependable list ccording to values in E2 and F2. Actually it works when I try this regular and enter formula manually in Data Validation, but when I try it with VBA, this happen'

Comment: There is no way to debug this code without test data.  You need to test each components of the formula independently.  (e.g. `Debug.Print Range("CONCATENATE($E2;"" 
"";$F2)").address`, Debug.Print `Evaluate("COUNTIF(PARTSDB!$A:$A;CONCATENATE($E2;"" 
"";$F2));1)"")`

Comment: That is excellent advice from @Thomas-Inzina ... Always try to break a code issue into smaller parts, to determine where the actual problem lies.  @Ivan-Kočiš, do you know how to [use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716276(v=vs.60).aspx) `debug.print` with the Immediate Window, as Thomas suggested?

Comment: @ashleedawg also excellent advice.  This may help: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 3 - What to do When Things Go Wrong (Errors and Debugging)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=DlqKfYTgc9Q&index=3&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: Yes, thnx @Thomas Inzina and @ashleedawg. I broke the code in chunks and found error in CONCATENATE but I`m looking why do I have problem with concatenate now. Both cell have values (E2=1SN01B & F2=M) and concatenation output have it`s key in range of PARTSDB!A:A. When I do all things manually it works. Looks like I messed up formula and concatenation, but I dont see how!

Comment: Whoa, that's impossible to troubleshoot without sample data or a definition of "do all things manually".

Comment: Sorry, didnt know how to express it properly. When I go trough excel and Data>Data Validation> Select List and enter in SOURCE =OFFSET(PARTSDB!$A$1;MATCH(CONCATENATE($E2;" ";$F2);PARTSDB!$A:$A;0)-1;1;COUNTIF(PARTSDB!$A:$A;CONCATENATE($E2;" ";$F2));1) I get what I need and everything goes OK. But when I try same thing trough VBA I get error 1004! Btw, In cell E2 is 1SN01B, in Cell F2=M and in PartsDB! sheet amoung various other styles/sizes in A & B column there is one line with same combination (A56= 1SN01B M). What I need back is from B56:B59 = list: Patina, Label, Elastic and Spalina!

Comment: @Thomas Inzina, yes, but in case of Countif it doesnt need to be range, it is criteria!

Comment: You are probably having an issue escaping the double quotes.  The easy way to escape the quotes is to paste the formula in a cell then run this in the Immediate Window: `Replace(ActiveCell.Formula,Chr(34),Chr(34) & Chr(34))`

Comment: Ooh I see that now.  The ID? returned from the formula looked like a partial range...oops.

Comment: So it means that A56, A57, A58, A59 are all 1SN01B M and I need a range of corresponding cells from B column back as a list. Strange is that it works when I enter that in excel Data>Data Validation>List Source=formula... and in VBA it doesnt1

Comment: Im sorry @Thomas Inzina, Im not sure I follow this. What to replace?

Comment: I believe your issue stems from improperly escaped double quotes. The code I posted above will escape the double quotes correctly for you.

Comment: Oh I get that, but where to put it, after formula or?

Comment: @Thomas Inzina, Ive tried your method but no luck as it get error before reaching your code. Ive tried this using your logic (it is logical that what you mentioned could be the issue): `.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=OFFSET(PARTSDB!$A$1;MATCH(CONCATENATE([MODEL];" & Chr(34) & Chr(32) & Chr(34) & ";[VELICINA]);PARTSDB!$A:$A;0)-1;1;COUNTIF(PARTSDB!$A:$A;CONCATENATE([MODEL];" & Chr(34) & Chr(32) & Chr(34) & ";[VELICINA]));1)"`

Comment: Pretty sure formulas added via VBA use the comma separator and not semicolon.  If it were a cell formula you could use FormulaLocal and still use semicolons: not sure if there's an equivalent for a validation formula though.

Comment: @Tim Williams, this is passing formula to excel and not exactly creating formula in VBA. In that case I believe it can goe with semi-colon (at least with my regional settings)

Comment: @IvanKočiš have you recorded I macro of you manually setting the cell validation?

Comment: @TimWilliams I believe that the `;` delimiter is a regional setting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341258/write-a-formula-in-an-excel-cell-using-vba

Comment: @ThomasInzina - yes, but Excel only understands the local setting if you're entering the formula manually: if you use VBA it only understands comma.  EDIT - I am not certain this applies to Validation formulas though...

Comment: @ThomasInzina yes I did. Thats how I originally created code, it was much faster... It is all a bit strange to me! I tried several times...

Comment: @TimWilliams for just in case I tried that too, but no luck!

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for the clarification.  In that case try `Formula1:="=OFFSET(PARTSDB!$A$1,MATCH(CONCATENATE($E2,"" "",$F2),PARTSDB!$A:$A,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(PARTSDB!$A:$A,CONCATENAT??E($E2,"""",$F2)),1)"`

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/21155-translate-formula1-conditional-formats-english-fo.html  seems like Conditional Formatting and Data Validation use the current locale, even when setting formulas in VBA.  So I was on the wrong track...

Comment: @ThomasInzina thnx for pointing on possible issue but it didnt solved the problem in this case. Ive tried it!

Comment: @Tim, sorry, it did help eventually with commas but I changed my regional settings too. Strange, never happen' before!