# VBA: Formula with double quotes

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a formula to a cell via VBA, but for some reason fail to get it done.

I've tried

```
ws.Range("O2").Formula = "=DATEDIF($N$2;C1+1;""m"")/3+1"
```

Error message is 1004 ("Application-defined or object-defined error")

```
ws.Range("O2").Formula = "=DATEDIF($N$2;C1+1;" & Char(34) & "m" & Char(34) & ")/3+1"
```

Error message here is "Sub or function not defined"

How do I do this?

Comment: Try Chr(34) ...

Comment: Try `FormulaLocal`

Comment: If that doesn't work, enter the formula manually on the worksheet; make sure it works; then examine the `Range.Formula` property of the cell in which you placed it.

Comment: Use comma(,) in place of semicolon (;) `ws.Range("O2").Formula = "=DATEDIF($N$2,C1+1," & Char(34) & "m" & Char(34) & ")/3+1"`. This has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341258/write-a-formula-in-an-excel-cell-using-vba) before .

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Thank you, somehow I missed this (despite making this mistake before).

Comment: VBA can be "us-centric", especially with regard to formulas.  So you have to  either use the `.FormulaLocal` property, or write using the US style formulas.